# How to scroll .list-group leaving navigation bar at top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wrote the following code. I want to make the scroll only for the .list-group. If you try scrolling the code below, you will see that the top navigation bar disappears after scrolling vertically. I want it to stay but the .list-group to scroll. Tried to set up the css settings for body and .list-group, but seems like I'm doing it wrong. How can I do it?

(The .list-group is filled using underscore template after fetching the data from server).

```css
body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.list-group {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.container {} .nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #555555;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #4ab4c5;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="main_container">
  <h2><span class="label label-primary">CONFERENCE</span></h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-responsive">
    <li class="active"><a data="1" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Simposium Sessions</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Poster Sessions</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Exhibitors</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4">Sightseeing Schedule</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu5">History</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu6">INFORMATION</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tabs" class="tab-content">
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>Simposium Sessions</h3>
      <div id="abstracts_oral">
        <div class="list-group">

          <a class="list-group-item" data-id="0">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><span class="text-center">topic </span></h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Author:it humanity raillery an unpacked as he.</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Time:12:12</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Room Number:DK-300</p>
          </a>

          <a class="list-group-item" data-id="1">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><span class="text-center">topic </span></h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Author:it humanity raillery an unpacked as he.</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Time:12:12</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Room Number:DK-300</p>
          </a>

          <a class="list-group-item" data-id="2">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><span class="text-center">topic </span></h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Author:it humanity raillery an unpacked as he.</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Time:12:12</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Room Number:DK-300</p>
          </a>

          <a class="list-group-item" data-id="3">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><span class="text-center">topic </span></h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Author:it humanity raillery an unpacked as he.</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Time:12:12</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Room Number:DK-300</p>
          </a>

          <a class="list-group-item" data-id="4">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><span class="text-center">topic </span></h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Author:it humanity raillery an unpacked as he.</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Time:12:12</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Room Number:DK-300</p>
          </a>

          <a class="list-group-item" data-id="5">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><span class="text-center">topic </span></h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Author:it humanity raillery an unpacked as he.</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Time:12:12</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Room Number:DK-300</p>
          </a>

          <a class="list-group-item" data-id="6">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><span class="text-center">topic </span></h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Author:it humanity raillery an unpacked as he.</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Time:12:12</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Room Number:DK-300</p>
          </a>




        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Poster Sessions</h3>
      <div id="abstracts_poster">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Exhibitors</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu4" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Sightseeing Schedule</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu5" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>History</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu6" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Info</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution, if you fix the header in place - see my CSS code comments below.

Alternatively you could apply a fixed height to .list-group, e.g. 500px and then it would scroll also for you.

```css
body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 155px; /* set this to your header height */
}
.list-group {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.container {} .nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #555555;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #4ab4c5;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
#header {
  position: fixed; /* keep at the top of the page */
  height: 155px; /* header height */
  width: 100%; /* required to fill the page width */
  top: 0; /* stay at the top of the page */
  left: 0; /* stay on the left of the page */
  padding: 0 15px; /* match padding on bootstrap */
  z-index: 10; /* make the header sit on top */
  background: white; /* transparent background won't look right here */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="main_container">
<div id="header">
  <h2><span class="label label-primary">CONFERENCE</span></h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-responsive">
    <li class="active"><a data="1" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Simposium Sessions</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Poster Sessions</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Exhibitors</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4">Sightseeing Schedule</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu5">History</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu6">INFORMATION</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
  <div id="tabs" class="tab-content">
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>Simposium Sessions</h3>
      <div id="abstracts_oral">
        <div class="list-group">

          <a class="list-group-item" data-id="0">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><span class="text-center">topic </span></h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Author:it humanity raillery an unpacked as he.</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Time:12:12</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Room Number:DK-300</p>
          </a>

          <a class="list-group-item" data-id="1">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><span class="text-center">topic </span></h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Author:it humanity raillery an unpacked as he.</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Time:12:12</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Room Number:DK-300</p>
          </a>

          <a class="list-group-item" data-id="2">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><span class="text-center">topic </span></h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Author:it humanity raillery an unpacked as he.</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Time:12:12</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Room Number:DK-300</p>
          </a>

          <a class="list-group-item" data-id="3">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><span class="text-center">topic </span></h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Author:it humanity raillery an unpacked as he.</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Time:12:12</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Room Number:DK-300</p>
          </a>

          <a class="list-group-item" data-id="4">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><span class="text-center">topic </span></h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Author:it humanity raillery an unpacked as he.</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Time:12:12</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Room Number:DK-300</p>
          </a>

          <a class="list-group-item" data-id="5">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><span class="text-center">topic </span></h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Author:it humanity raillery an unpacked as he.</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Time:12:12</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Room Number:DK-300</p>
          </a>

          <a class="list-group-item" data-id="6">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><span class="text-center">topic </span></h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Author:it humanity raillery an unpacked as he.</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Time:12:12</p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Room Number:DK-300</p>
          </a>




        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Poster Sessions</h3>
      <div id="abstracts_poster">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Exhibitors</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu4" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Sightseeing Schedule</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu5" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>History</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu6" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Info</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great, but there is one problem with it. Try running your snippet then press full screen (and resize window so that scoll appears). The navigation bar is too short in width. So scroll partially is seen on the right side of nav. bar.

Comment: I've added width: 100% to #header now, and that resolves the issue you've mentioned :)

Comment: sorry, i've tried this too, but the bottom line of the navbar goes till the end of the window (try making size of window long enough horizontally) :)

Comment: I've updated my answer now to also include left: 0; and padding: 0 15px; on the #header, this matches the bootstrap positioning for you.

Comment: Thanks man! It worked, but I used the javascript resize function to fix the height etc :)